# InternetOpenUrl and IMDB header

Tags: delphi, http-headers, delphi-7, imdb

I'm using code I found here to get movie titles from www.imdb.com and it works fine, but since imdb has some sort of geolocation I need to figure how to force the results in english with a "Accept-Language: en" header but I'm not sure if I can with this code. Is it possible?

```
uses
  WinInet,
  StrUtils,
  SysUtils;

function GetHTMLTitle(const Url:string):string;
    const
    BuffSize     = 64*1024;
    TitleTagBegin='<title>';
    TitleTagEnd  ='</title>';
    var
      hInter   : HINTERNET;
      UrlHandle: HINTERNET;
      BytesRead: Cardinal;
      Buffer   : Pointer;
      i,f      : Integer;
    begin
      Result:='';
      hInter := InternetOpen('', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
      if Assigned(hInter) then
      begin
        GetMem(Buffer,BuffSize);
        try
           UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrl(hInter, PChar(Url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,0);
           try
            if Assigned(UrlHandle) then
            begin
              InternetReadFile(UrlHandle, Buffer, BuffSize, BytesRead);
              if BytesRead>0 then
              begin
                SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(Buffer), BytesRead);
                i:=Pos(TitleTagBegin,Result);
                if i>0 then
                begin
                  f:=PosEx(TitleTagEnd,Result,i+Length(TitleTagBegin));
                  Result:=Copy(Result,i+Length(TitleTagBegin),f-i-Length(TitleTagBegin));
                end;
              end;
            end;
           finally
             InternetCloseHandle(UrlHandle);
           end;
        finally
          FreeMem(Buffer);
        end;
        InternetCloseHandle(hInter);
      end
    end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Title : string;
begin
  Title := GetHTMLTitle('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/');
  Label1.Caption := Copy(Title, 1, LastDelimiter(')', Title));
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of `InternetOpenUrl()` allows you to specify custom headers, eg:

```
UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrl(hInter, PChar(Url), 'Accept-Language: en', -1, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,0);
```

BTW, there is no guarantee that `InternetReadFile()` will return everything in a single buffer.  You should be calling it in a loop, appending each buffer to a local cache, until you have cached everything you need, then process the cache as needed.

**Update**: IMDB does indeed use IP geolocation, so apparently it does not use `Accept-Language` like it used to. You will have to adjust your HTTP requests according:

[Why am I seeing titles in a different language than before?](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?titlelanguagedisplay)

> We recently modified the way titles are displayed on the site. Users will now by default see titles listed in the language used for release in their country (i.e. US-based users will see films listed under the title used for the North American release, while users browsing the site from France will see titles as they appeared on the French release of those movies etc.)
>   If you are registered on IMDb.com and you prefer to see original titles, or the title in any other language/country of release by default, you can set your user preferences accordingly.
>
> To do this, please click on the 'Your Account' link (located in the upper right corner of every page on IMDb.com) and then click on the 'Site Preferences' option, or go directly to https://secure.imdb.com/register-imdb/siteprefs , and then choose the desired options from the "Title Display Country" and "Title Display Language" dropdown menus. Click 'OK' to save your choice.
>
> For more help/information, please refer to our site preferences help page.
>
> Please also remember that if you access the site through the following URL, you will always see films listed under their original titles regardless of your login status or site preferences:
>
> http://akas.imdb.com

Comment: Hmm, -1 as header length gives me error "Constant expression violates subrange bounds" even though your suggestion seems right according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: `DWORD` type value cannot be negative, so it cannot be -1. Though that docs mentions `-1L`, which is a value of -1 with so called long suffix. I believe it could be literally translated as `DWORD(LongInt(-1))` in Delphi.

Comment: I tried with indy's TidHttp component and it doesn't seem like imdb.com cares if I send Accept-language: en as a header.. Still get title in local language.. IP geolocation?

Comment: @TLama: it can be shortened to `DWORD(-1)`.

Comment: @Remy, that's right. I was just trying to translate it literally.

Comment: Even though akas.imdb.com is suppose to give you orginal title regardless of login status/preferences it doesn't. You'll still get title in your local language. I guess you have to be logged in to be able to do what I want, or search the source for original title tag..